# Identity URL always throwing Missing_OAuth_Token?

Tags: apex, oauth2, java, identity

```
     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(environment);
    post.addParameter("code", code);
    post.addParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    post.addParameter("redirect_uri", "https://******.ngrok.io/auth");
    post.addParameter("client_id", "3MVG9d8..z.hDcPLDlm9QqJ3hRa..IRUJdGRp4Shjuu01GT.H5KRjos_xlbZEtYGy55M6SzOOELg7sfD4T6Pl");
    post.addParameter("client_secret", "*********");
```

After executing this I get an access token:

`accessToken = jsonObject.get("access_token").getAsString();`
`useridURL = jsonObject.get("id").getAsString();`

with which I try to fire a get method to get the userinfo:

```
    GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(useridURL);
    getMethod.addRequestHeader("oauth_token", accessToken);
    httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
    String responseUserName = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

but I always get this error: `Missing_OAuth_Token`, I am not sure if I am missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header you are setting in GET request is not proper.

it should be Authorization instead of oauth_token.

According to SF docs:

> To call the doGet method from a client, open a command-line window and
>   execute the following cURL command to retrieve an account by ID:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer sessionId" "https://instance.salesforce.com/yourURL"
```

Thus your code will be:

```
getMethod.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
```

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm